# Pebble Watchface send message to Android App

Tags: java, javascript, android, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I'm trying to send a message from my Pebble Watchface (Not a pebble Watch app) to an Android application.

I have a js file as part of my Watchface that receives the messages no problem, but my android application is not receiving the message.

Is there a special way to target the Android application? Do I need to forward the message from the JS file to my Android application somehow?

I've received messages in my Android application from other watchfaces, so I'm not sure how they are doing it and I can't seem to find any documentation on how to target and Android application from a Watchface.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Hi @mparkes, I am facing same issue, can you put some code example on how to pass message from Watch and receive on Android. It will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use both PebbleKitJS and an Android app to talk to the same Pebble application.

As soon as you have JS in your app, it stops any communication from getting to your Android app, so you'll need to pick either JS or Android.

Comment: Thanks for a response, but I'm not sure this is entirely true.  I actually had a problem with the Android debugger and was able to solve my problem.  Messages are making to to my JS file and my Android application now.